# vim makes half of my text invisible sometimes

Tags: vim

Sometimes when I do certain actions such as opening a file or unfolding some text, the bottom half of my text does not appear. If I press an arrow key or something, it re-appears.

Here is a gif example of this happening. In the recording, I un-fold some code, and half of it is invisible. I then make the missing half re-appear by pressing an arrow key.

[image: screencast]

Is there a known way to fix this? I am using version 8.0.628

Comment: Is this gVim or terminal Vim? What terminal are you using and what is the value of `TERM`? Does it behave the same if you run in a different terminal app?

Comment: @Paul, $TERM = rxvt-unicode-256color. It does not seem to behave this way in xterm. I am not sure how to go about troubleshooting urxvt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the solution you are looking for but I do know pressing ctrl+l will reload the screen.  I rarely have the same issue as well and this is how I resolve the issue.